# Getting a List of computers on a network

Tags: java, networking, host

I have been trying to get the name or the ip of all computers on the network I am on in Java.

I have tried pinging for each one with 2 different ways:

```
Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 " + host);
returnval = p.waitFor();
```

This returns 0 for every address even when it fails.

and

```
InetAddress.getByAddress(host).isReachable(timeout);
```

Always returning false

The computers appear in Windows network tab in explorer.

Is there some way to retrieve a list of names of those computer in Java to use?

Comment: This is not a Java question. You know how to run external native programs, so your question is purely a Windows/Linux/MAC question.

Comment: What do use as a `host`?

Comment: have you tried [google your question](https://www.google.com/#q=java+get+a+list+of+computers+on+a+network)?

Comment: 10.25.144. (from 0 to 254).

Comment: Are you reading the response from the process.  What does *"However both do not work"* actually mean?  Did they throw and exception, fail to run not report anything??

Comment: @Funkydiddykong then it's customary to accept an answer. That shows people you don't need more help/comments/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows?

```
net view
```

or

```
arp -a
```

Last one gives MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Xabsters answer I was able to achieve a list via the following code.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process p = rt.exec("arp -a");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.trim();
            if (!s.startsWith("I") && s.length >0)
            System.out.println(s.split(" ")[0]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a complement to above answers.

`InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout);` which would be the java way of doing this (portable across different architectures), did not work because it expects a host **name**. When using IP addresses, you should use :

```
InetAddress.getByAddress(host).isReachable(timeout);
```

That is the platform independant way.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the question.